# Simple Rdoc Question about documentation modifiers

Tags: ruby, rdoc

I have this method in a class I am using

```
def binary_search(a,x)
  # ...
end
```

and I want in the documentation for the parameters to appear as `def binary_search(array, key)` and not `binary_search(a,x)`. I have tried to use the documentation modifier `# :binary_search: array, key` with no success. I know this a little thing, but if somebody knows how to do make the parameters different in the documentation than in the actual source code, can you please show me? Thanks.

Comment: Simply don't use short variable names?

Comment: Yes I know and I don't. I just asked this question out of curiosity.

Comment: Putting "Question" in a question title is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to be able to use the [`:call-seq:`](http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/RDoc/Parser/Ruby.html) directive in the method header comment as follows:

```
##
# Pass array and key.
#
# :call-seq:
#   binary_search(array, key)
def binary_search(a, x)
  # ...
end
```

I haven't got this working yet. I'm using RDoc V1.0.1 and Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work on my system either and I'm running Ruby 1.9.2 with RDoc 2.5.8

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try `# :args: thing_to_try` like so: (be careful about whitespace)

```
# rdoc-2.5.8/lib/rdoc/parser/ruby.rb:48
# The parser extracts the arguments from the method definition.  You can
# override this with a custom argument definition using the :args: directive:

   ##
   # This method tries over and over until it is tired 

   def go_go_go(thing_to_try, tries = 10) # :args: thing_to_try
     puts thing_to_try
     go_go_go thing_to_try, tries - 1
   end
```